# How to handle the when patch is applied twice on the same file in Ubuntu 14

Tags: unix, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, diff, patch

I am trying to handle the patch test case when executed twice, for the first execution the script runs fine but when I try to execute the same script without reversing the patch the script exits with error code `[exit 1]`

Script:

```
patch -p0 --dry-run < patchfile
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    patch -p0 < patchfile
else
    echo "Patch already applied"
fi
```

I have similar issue in handling the patch to reverse the changes with option `-R`

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? `patch` already does this if you just omit `--dry-run`.

Comment: I trying to handle the case with capturing the exit code in `$?` if the same script is executed twice consequently. My approach might be wrong though.

Comment: Don't write code around `patch`, just call it!  When applying the same patch twice, `patch` will report that and fail, which is what your code is trying to do. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to convey. I have a script which does a couple of steps and one of the step is executing patch on a particular directory. So to handle the scenario if the same script is executed twice (without reversing the patch) the `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then` doesn't capture it. The script simply exits with the error code `[exit 1]`
I want to make sure the script handles the scenario of executing the patch command twice which should not fail

Comment: Could there be a `set -e` somewhere before the patch command? Verify by adding `echo before false; false; echo after false` before the test and check that both echo statements run.

Comment: @hlovdal It worked, thank you!